# How to useState on a form input with predefined value?

Tags: forms, react-hooks, preact, freshjs

I want to have a form with a default value, and whatever value users input will be caught. Here is my code:

```js
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function test() {
  const [field1Value, setInput] = useState("");
  return (
    <div class="gap-2 w-full">
      <input
        value = 'Default value'
        onInput={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)}
      />
      {field1Value} 
    </div>
  );
}
```

If the form only has `value` and not `onInput`, or vice versa, then it works as expected. But if both of them appear, then users can't change it. It looks like this:

[image]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the value of the input to a hardcoded value  `value = 'Default value'` You need to set it to the field value `value={field1Value}` and then set the predefined value in the input state

```js
 const [field1Value, setInput] = useState("Default Value");
```

```js
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function test() {
  const [field1Value, setInput] = useState("Default Value");
  return (
    <div class="gap-2 w-full">
       <input
        value={field1Value}
        placeholder="Enter value"
        onInput={(event) => setInput(event.target.value)}
      />
      {field1Value} 
    </div>
  );
}
```